# Using Hibernate property Projection to fetch association and inject it to Dto

Tags: hibernate, associations, projection, many-to-one

I have a Entity (MediaCostRule) that has several regular fields and one association fields annotated with @ElementCollection (MediaCostRuleSource)

I also have a dto (MediaCostRuleDto) that holds subset of the Entity fields and also includes the same  association set

Here is the classes code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "media_cost_rules")
public class MediaCostRule extends AdminEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "media_cost_rule_id")
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "name")
@Length(max = 100)
private String name;

@Column(name="is_enabled")
private Boolean enabled;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
private Brand brand;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "media_cost_rule_sources", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "media_cost_rule_id"))
private Set<MediaCostRuleSource> mediaCostRuleSources = new HashSet<MediaCostRuleSource>();
```

=====================================================================

```
@Embeddable
public class MediaCostRuleSource {


@Column(name = "source_name")
private String sourceName;

@Column(name = "ordinal")
private Integer ordinal;
```

==================================================================

```
public class MediaCostRuleDto extends AbstractAdminDto {


@Size(min = 1)
private Set<MediaCostRuleSource> mediaCostRuleSources = new HashSet<MediaCostRuleSource>();


@NotNull
private String name;
```

===========================================================================

Now what I would like is to use Projections in order to fetch just the mediaCostRuleSources and name of my entity and to have it injected directly to my MediaCostRuleDto (using AliasToBeanResultTransformer).

I have tried the following code:

```
@Test
public void findByIdDirectTest2(){

    Criteria crit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(MediaCostRule.class).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("name").as("name"));
    projectionList.add(Projections.property("mediaCostRuleSources").as("mediaCostRuleSources"));
    crit.setProjection(projectionList);
    List list = crit.list();
}
```

But I am always getting exceptions (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException)

There must be some kind of way to do such thing with Hibernate

Do you know how ??

Yosi

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
crit.setFetchMode("mediaCostRuleSources",FetchMode.JOIN)
```